# Scikit-learn's Gaussian Processes Classifier: Specific kernels for specific features

Tags: scikit-learn, gaussian-process

Using GaussianProcessClassifier from sklearn, is it possible to specify different kernels for different features?  For example, $X$ is an n X 2 matrix and I would to use the RBF for the first column and DotProduct for the second column.  I think what I have below is combining everything.

```
kernel = ConstantKernel(1.0) * RBF(length_scale=1.0)+DotProduct()
gpc = GaussianProcessClassifier(kernel=kernel)
```

Comment: A quick glance at the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.gaussian_process.GaussianProcessClassifier.html) suggests **no**.

Comment: ```kernelkernel instance, default=None

    The kernel specifying the covariance function of the GP. If None is passed, the kernel “1.0 * RBF(1.0)” is used as default. Note that the kernel’s hyperparameters are optimized during fitting. Also kernel cannot be a CompoundKernel.
```